# My system call is not working properly

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I need to create 2 new system calls to set and get a property from a process by the given pid. I changed task_struct, added int z_value (this is what I need to set/get)

I also managed to set a default z_value (200) for every process created.

When I run get system call, I can see that default z_value correct. But when I try to set the z_value nothing happens.

No compiling errors, no segmentation fault etc.

Here is my set system call.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

asmlinkage void sys_set_z_value ( int user_value , pid_t pid )
{


    rcu_read_lock();

    struct task_struct *p = find_task_by_vpid(pid);  

    p->z_value = user_value;

    rcu_read_unlock();
}
```

Comment: Can you not extend an existing call, for example prctl? Alternatively, write a char device with some ioctls which perform the function?

Answer (score 6):

Your call to `copy_from_user` makes no sense. There's no pointer to userspace memory involved. `user_value` is a value, not a pointer. (If you intended for it to be a pointer, you need to fix the types involved, but it looks like you're passing this `int` by value to the syscall.) Just assign `p->z_value = user_value;`.

Comment: +1. I noticed the value/pointer confusion, but wasn't sure if the `copy_from_user` was even necessary here.

Comment: By the way, I've never written and hardly ever read Linux kernel code, so my answer is based simply on a logical reading of the name of the function `copy_from_user` and the types and arguments involved. Hopefully it's right, though. :-)

Comment: @melih: Yes, that's what I think. `copy_from_user` is almost surely wrong at least.

Comment: @melih: given that the user's input is available as a parameter of type `int`, it's already in kernel space. Only pointer inputs (pathnames etc.) need to be copied. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-system-calls/

Comment: I removed copy_from_user but it didn't work. I think I should read more about processes, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

- Your syscall should return a `long` type.
- You should use the `SYSCALL_DEFINE2()` macros.
- Your code should not compile without warnings (and declaring the `p` type in the middle of the function will trigger a warning)
- If you get an invalid pid, your `p` variable will be `NULL`, and you should return `-ESRCH`

About this:

> I also managed to set a default z_value (200) for every process created.

I hope that you took care of `init_task` too, it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) Introduce an intentional error like some random characters in the source file and make sure your kernel build fails.  Its amazing the number of problems that come down to the code you add not being built.

assuming that wasn't it

2) Load up your code with a lot of printk's so you can see what it's trying to do by either watching the console window or invoking dmesg after you've run it.  Put them all over the place to check every assumption - that the code runs, that the variables are what you think, etc.